# Is it possible to send data (TraceID to be precise) from Spring Cloud API gateway to a microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have an api gateway and a microservice. I have incorporated Spring cloud sleuth in my project but I am getting the incorrect Trace IDs. For example, if the gateway calls a microservice, both of them are supposed to have the same traceId but this is what I get -

API Gateway Logs

```
2021-06-22 11:00:13.446 INFO [gateway, 3ad39a60c4ac0e95, 3ad39a60c4ac0e95] 776 [ctor-http-nio-2] c.m.c.u.config.APIRoutes Locator : Routes are
```

Microservice Logs

```
2021-06-22 11:00:34.285 INFO [service1, 2a758b1cb504ca75,62e0509ed861a50f, true] 556 [nio-8000-exec-5] c.m.c.u.service.MasterReport Service: Fetching latest business date
```

I get a completely new TraceId in the microservice and I do not know from where that one originates.

So now, I was wondering whether it is possible to send the traceID from the gateway to the microservice so that I can replace the one that's showing up in the logs...

Comment: "So now, I was wondering whether it is possible to send the traceID from the gateway to the microservice". Well, that's what Sleuth should be doing. Have you done any configuration in Sleuth?

Comment: I don't think I have. All I did was add the sleuth dependency to my build.gradle file and added a few log.info() statements. Am I supposed to ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you contact another service? via http request? If so, try defining a RestTemplate bean in the class where you perform template.exchange(...), it solved the problem for me:

```
// Define this bean in some config class or directly in controller
@Bean
public RestTemplate template() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

// And autowire it in the controller class
@Autowired
private RestTemplate template;

public String call() {
return template.exchange(...);
```